# Matrix elements combination

Tags: algorithm, loops, matrix

There is a m x n array, I need to output each possible combination Of each line's element. For example, for array`{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}`, I need to output`{{1,4},{1,5},{1,6},{2,4},{2,5},{2,6},{3,4},{3,5},{3,6}}`.

---

I think there should be a m loop to solve this. For the example above, I wrote the code:

```
        int[,] array = new int[,] {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{{{array[0, i]},{array[1, j]}}}");
            }
        }
```

With m changes, the number of `for` loop also changes. But m is unknown when I write the code. How can I solve it?

Comment: Please remove the algorithm tag and add a relevant language tag

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a list of active combinations `c`. Initialize `c` to be the array's first row. Then iterate every additional row and update `c`. Basically, you augment each of the current combinations with each of the row's items. Here is some pseudo code:

```
c = array[0]; //read: the first row of the array
for(var i = 1; i < m; ++i) { //iterate all rows
    var c_modified = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < n; ++j) { //iterate all row entries
        for(var k = 0; k < c.length; ++k) { //iterate all entries of c
            add c[k].array[i, j] to c_modified; // . represents concatenation
        }
    }
    c = c_modified;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This combination of elements (`n^m` sets) is called Cartesian product. There are ready-to-use functions for its generation in some language libraries

I believe that the simplest code is recursive one.

```
type
  TArr2D = TArray<TArray<Integer>>;

procedure CartesianProduct(const A: TArr2D; Line: Integer; Reslt: TArray<Integer>);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  if Line > High(A) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ArrayToString(Reslt)) // output m-element set
  else
    for i in A[Line] do
       CartesianProduct(A, Line + 1, Reslt + [i]);  // include element in set
end;

var
  A: TArr2D;
  n, m, i, j: Integer;
begin
  m := 3;
  n := 3;
  SetLength(A, m, n);
  for j := 0 to m - 1 do
    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
       A[j, i] := j * n + i;
    //0 1 2
    //3 4 5
    //6 7 8

  CartesianProduct(A, 0, []);
```

gives

```
0 3 6 
0 3 7 
0 3 8 
0 4 6 
0 4 7 
0 4 8 
0 5 6 
0 5 7 
0 5 8 
1 3 6 
1 3 7 
1 3 8 
1 4 6 
1 4 7 
1 4 8 
1 5 6 
1 5 7 
1 5 8 
2 3 6 
2 3 7 
2 3 8 
2 4 6 
2 4 7 
2 4 8 
2 5 6 
2 5 7 
2 5 8
```